# header text box align with the other boxes

Tags: html, css

I am trying to adjust this code to make the header text box align with the other three text boxes below but I can't get it right

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px auto;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

.container-head img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: &60
}

.container-first {
  background: #eee;
}

.container-second {
  background: #fff;
}

.container-third {
  background: #eee;
}

.container-first,
.container-second,
.container-third {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  width: 760;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-head">
  <img src="http://media.eloqua.com/designimages/new-oracle-logo2.png" />
</div>
<div class="container-first">
  <p>first</p>
</div>
<div class="container-second">
  <p>second</p>
</div>
<div class="container-third">
  <p>third</p>
</div>
```

Comment: What specifically goes wrong? Please help clarify what you're aiming to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Add width to container-head 760px;

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Eloqua HTML Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
    body { background:#ccc; font-family:'Arial', sans-serif; }
    div { position:relative; margin:0px auto; margin-bottom:30px; border:1px solid #333;  }
    .container-head img { display:block; margin:0px auto; width:&60}
    .container-first { background:#eee; }
    .container-second { background:#fff; }
    .container-third { background:#eee; }
    .container-first, .container-second, .container-third,.container-head{ padding:10px 10px; width:760;}
</style>
</head>  
<body>
<div class="container-head">
<img src="http://media.eloqua.com/designimages/new-oracle-logo2.png" />
</div>
<div class="container-first">
<p>first</p>
</div>
<div class="container-second">
<p>second</p>
</div>
<div class="container-third">
<p>third</p>
</div>  
</body></html>
```

here

```
.container-first, .container-second, .container-third,.container-head{ padding:10px 10px; width:760;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to display them Horizontally ? If so then use a NAVBAR..  Change your content

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
</div>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
</ul>
 </div>
</nav>
```

OR

if you want to change the size of image block same as other three then use

```
<div class="container-head" style="width:58%;" >
<img src="http://media.eloqua.com/designimages/new-oracle-logo2.png" />
</div>
```